# Looking for large summary table hex OPCODE - asm

Tags: assembly

Once it was rewritten by hand decades ago from 286 architecture book. It looked like:

```
x    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    A    B    C    D    E

0    ADD    ADDW
   rm,reg   rm,reg
1
....................

F   LOCK    REP/REPNE/
             REPNZ
```

It's extremely handy. Have you seen such a table. I need for contemporary x86 microprocessor.
I don't believe it doesn't exist for it's indispensable.

Comment: What CPU are you looking for?

Comment: popular x86 intel, amd . It looks like similar in format to 286 http://www.physics.mcmaster.ca/tech/HC908/opcode_map.gif . So i need any. Just (may be you dont know but it's the table of the first hex 8 bits) the second is changing. So it really doesn't matter. Only difficult in finding such format matters

Comment: http://ftp.m1089.net/doc/txt/286&386.TXT -found, Here it is but I need mb secondary bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in Appendix A of [Intel Manual 2B](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253667.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't install USE="-pdf" on Gentoo, thanks. Could you please provide jpg or other picture format (providing it contains 2d one-page table in similar format like I gave).

Comment: @xsi it's a bit much to copy really, especially with the explanation of the abbreviations.

Comment: Your huge compendium is now in the process of conversion http://pdf2jpg.net/ (currently page 50). Ok I'll wait and I'm searching)

Comment: Ok that should work I guess, it's from page 630 to 655 or something

Comment: omg what did I expected. It's pdf cut, so only 1/2 of A4 page is non-empty. and yes, 645+ page contains 0-7h then next pages and next - continue table. So I need at least to concatenate. It would be my task for the next several hours. Anyway thx for work